# Use the 8-bit version of the IEEE 754 floating point format to find the representation of 32 to the base 10

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, ieee-754

> Using the following 8-bit version of the IEEE 754 floating point format as seen in the practicals: represent 32 to the base 10
>
> ```
> Sign 1-bit    Expontent 3-bits    Mantissa 4-bits
> ```

I was expecting not enough mantissa bits due to we have 3 bits to represent the exponent. We can represent 2^3 =8 numbers with 8 bits. The bias is considered to be half of it minus 1 so that we can represent both positive and negative exponents.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it. Like actually ask us a question, or describe the problem you have and what you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, if one of the encodings is reserved for infinity/NaN, and exponent values are centered around 0 the same as IEEE [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Notable_single-precision_cases), the highest positive exponent would be 3 (like from a 2-bit unsigned or 3-bit signed field).

And exponent = 3 means a multiplier of 2^3 = 8.  The maximum mantissa is `1 + 0xf / 16` = 1.9375, so the largest finite value is 15.5.

Converting 16 or higher to this format would overflow to +Inf.

If the format uses exponent = all-ones (0b111) for finite values, not having any Inf/NaN bit-patterns (which would make sense when there are so few bit-patterns), the max exponent could be higher by 1, allowing e=4.

```
(1 + 15/16) * 2^4  =  31
```

Depending on how you handle overflow, `32` might convert to `0x7F` (all bits set except for the sign), with a rounding error of 1.  It does overflow (unless your exponent encodings don't follow the normal [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) pattern).  It would raise an FP exception, but if exceptions are masked then you'd get some bit-pattern as a result.  IEEE 754 has a bit-pattern for Infinity to handle this case so there aren't rules for what to do without that.

If you want `32` to be representable without overflow, you'll have to sacrifice some negative exponents, shifting the bias so an exponent of 5 is encodeable.

---

Other formats work differently, like Posit having gradual overflow and being designed to be useful with few bits, including 8-bit. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format) /   https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/04/11/anatomy-of-a-posit-number/)